# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS disconnect from Wifi when another device connect

Tags: wireless, networking, android

Novice Ubuntu user here. I have a very strange problem.

I have a wireless connection at home. At one time there could be 3 machines that are connected using wireless (Windows 7 laptop, Window XP desktop and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS laptop). Normally everything runs just fine however the problem arise when I try to connect my Android phone to the network. Once my smartphone connect to the network successfully the Ubuntu laptop will disconnect EVERY TIME. I normally use the Windows 7 laptop for work & web and use the Ubuntu to watch TV shows online.

The funny thing is I've had guest at my house and they can connect there device (iPhone, Ipad, Galaxy tablet etc etc) to my network and the Ubuntu machine is fine. But as soon as I connect my little Samsung Galaxy, within 2-5 minutes, the Ubuntu will drop the connection entirely. Sometimes it will attempt to reconnect while sometimes it will just stay disconnected.

Any idea what is happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The same thing is happening with my Ubuntu 14.04LTS install. When any other device connect it seems fine but when my Android phone connect (or reset) Ubuntu will disconnect from Wifi almost IMMEDIATELY. Help!!!